# Can I share the import files with lots of python scripts

Tags: python-3.x

I have lots of python scripts, they share common module like the following sample

How could I extract them into another file like `common_includes.py`

And in each python file, I only need to  do `require common_includes`

```
    #!usr/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import requests
    import itertools
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    from lxml import etree
    import lxml
    import lxml.html as html
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import json
    import requests
    import os
    import urllib.parse
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.error
    from re import sub
    from decimal import Decimal
    from pdb import set_trace
    import datetime
    import pymongo
    import yaml
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a python file `.py` containing the imports listed and make the file name `common_includes.py (from example)`. Now when you want to link the file to your other ones, just include this at the top.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Python Scripts') # Filepath
import common_includes # Filename | do not add .py
```

You only need to use `sys` module if the common_includes file is not located in the same directory as the file you're working with.

Now, when importing you can either use:

```
import common_includes
import common_includes as CI
from common_includes import *

#Using the modules (os module as example)
common_includes.os
CI.os
os
```

To check it linked, just run a blank file with the code provided at the top and use one of the modules.